# is it easy to modify this python code to use pandas and would it help if i did?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have written a Python 2.7 script that reads a CSV file and then does some standard deviation calculations . It works absolutely fine however it is very very slow. A CSV I tried with 100 million lines took around 28 hours to complete. I did some googling and it appears that maybe using the pandas module might makes this quicker .

I have posted part of the code below, since i am a pretty novice when it comes to python , i am unsure if using pandas would actually help at all and if it did would the function need to be completely re-written.

Just some context for the CSV file, it has 3 columns, first column is an IP address, second is a url and the third is a timestamp.

```
def parseCsvToDict(filepath):
    with open(csv_file_path) as f: 
        ip_dict = dict()
        csv_data = csv.reader(f)
        f.next()                            # skip header line
        for row in csv_data:
            if len(row) == 3:   #Some lines in the csv have more/less than the 3 fields they should have so this is a cheat to get the script working ignoring an wrong data
                current_ip, URI, current_timestamp = row
                epoch_time = convert_time(current_timestamp)  # convert each time to epoch
                if current_ip not in ip_dict.keys():
                    ip_dict[current_ip] = dict()
                if URI not in ip_dict[current_ip].keys():
                    ip_dict[current_ip][URI] = list()
                ip_dict[current_ip][URI].append(epoch_time)
    return(ip_dict)
```

Once the above function has finished the data is parsed to another function that calculates the standard deviation for each IP/URL pair (using `numpy.std`).

Do you think that using pandas may increase the speed and would it require a complete rewrite or is it easy to modify the above code?

Comment: IMO, pandas is not the right strategy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = ["current_IP", "URI", "current_timestamp", "dummy"]
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, names=colnames)
# Remove incomplete and redundant rows:
df = df[~df.current_timestamp.isnull() & df.dummy.isnull()]
```

Notice this assumes you have enough RAM. In your code, you are already assuming you have enough memory for the dictionary, but the latter may be significatively smaller than the memory used by the above, for two reasons.

1. If it is because most lines are dropped, then just parse the csv by chunks: arguments `skiprows` and `nrows` are your friends, and then `pd.concat`
2. If it is because IPs/URLs are repeated, then you will want to transform IPs and URLs from normal columns to indices: parse by chunks as above, and on each chunk do

   ```
   indexed = df.set_index(["current_IP", "URI"]).sort_index()
   ```

I expect this will indeed give you a performance boost.

**EDIT:** ... including a performance boost to the calculation of the standard deviation (hint: `df.groupby()`)

Answer (score 1):

I will not be able to give you an exact solution, but here are a couple of ideas.

Based on your data, you read `100000000. / 28 / 60 / 60` approximately `1000` lines per second. Not really slow, but I believe that just reading such a big file can cause a problem.

So take a look at this [performance comparison](http://effbot.org/zone/readline-performance.htm) of how to read a huge file. Basically a guy suggests that doing this:

```
file = open("sample.txt")
while 1:
    lines = file.readlines(100000)
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines:
        pass # do something
```

can give you like 3x read boost. I also suggest you to try [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of your `if k in dict` create `[]` otherwise `append`.

And last, not related to python: working in data-analysis, I have found an amazing tool for working with csv/json. It is [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html), which allows to manipulate csv data with ease.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Salvador Dali said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32795115/897968): If you want to keep as much of the current code of your script, you may find that [PyPy can speed up your program](http://pypy.org/):

> “If you want your code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy.” — Guido van Rossum (creator of Python)

Comment: AFAIK, numpy support is poor atm. Probably not the best strategy.